# Correcting drive letters after a partition clone

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, boot, partitioning, clone

I have an old XP computer with 3 drives:

- Disk0 = C: D: E: F: (my current boot drive)
- Disk1 = I: (a data drive)
- Disk2 = J: K: L: M: (A new 2x bigger drive in an USB external case)

J is a "partition clone" of C (but J is double the size)
(Same "partition clone" done for D>K E>L F>M)  No "disk cloning" was done.

Computer Management reports:

- C is System (but no reference if it's BOOT or ACTIVE)
- J is Active (but no reference if it's BOOT or SYSTEM)

How can I remove Disk0 from the machine... and install Disk1... and have
Disk1 become my new C: D: E: F: boot drive?

I know I have already done this poorly... **but I need to do this *WITHOUT* 
another very long cloning process.**   (I've already cloned again and again 
trying to get this working.)

I can't use Disk Management:

- To change C to J... or any letter at all.
- I can't change J to C... already in use.
- I can't "remove" C to allow its latter reuse as J.
- I can't "swap" letters C and J.  Directly... or indirectly... with a "temporary go-between letter".

I'm sure Microsoft had its reasons for making this so complex, confusing, and time consuming... but I can't guess why.

Help!

Comment: Ideally you need to edit the Registry *before* you clone the logical-drive/partition of a system.  That is, the entries for drive assignments and volume IDs under `Computer` / `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` / `SYSTEM` / `MountedDevices` should be deleted (before a shutdown and cloning a **C:** drive).  There is supposed to be a way to edit the registry post-clone, but I've never done it that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can mess with the boot order/rule if you start CMD and type `msconfig`

---

To change an existing drive letter on a drive, on a partition, or on a volume, follow these steps:

1.Log on as Administrator or as a member of the Administrators group.

2.Click Start, click Control Panel, and then click Performance and Maintenance.

3.Click Administrative Tools, double-click Computer Management, and then click Disk Management in the left pane.

4.Right-click the drive, the partition, the logical drive, or the volume that you want to assign a drive letter to, and then click
        Change Drive Letter and Paths.

5.Click Change.

6.Click Assign the following drive letter if it is not already selected, click the drive letter that you want to use, and then
        click OK.

7.Click Yes when you are prompted to confirm the drive letter change. The drive letter of the drive, the partition, or the volume
        that you specified is changed, and the new drive letter appears in
        the appropriate drive, partition, or volume in the Disk Management
        tool.

For more information, read [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/307844)

Comment: But what would I change in my particular case?   I can't change C to J... or anything else.  I can't change J to C either.  Already in use.  I need to *REMOVE* C.  Also impossible.  I also can't change C to a temporary (unused) letter as an intermediate solution.

Comment: Boot into Windows PE and change as required

Answer (score 0):

You need to access a partition manager, such as GParted, and modify the partition that corresponds to `J:` such that it has the boot/system flag set.

Once you are able to boot into Windows with only your new disk (this might not be trivial), go to `Disk Management` and remap all of your drive letters to your former ones, if need be.

Comment: I'll try to find GParted and figure out how to change J to a boot/system partition.   At boot-up, won't step 2 immediately start changing my registry settings to "C is not found.  Change all references to J".

Comment: @user-460704 I'm sure the boot drive is always mapped to C..